# How to save pandas dataframe generated dynmically as column values as .csv file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe and it has an Id column header with values, now I want to generate new column values using the index length concatenating underscore and predefined constant which would increase as the index increases. For example if the there are 3 indexes. The value should be 1_1,1_2 and 2_1 and so on.

```
dfm = pd.DataFrame({'Id' : [4,9,7,8,3,1]})
l=len(dfm.index)
def gen(l):
  lst=[]
  for i in range(1,l+1):
    for j in range(1,7):
      z="{}{}{}".format(i,'_', j)
      lst.append((z))
  return lst

>>> k=gen(l)
>>> k
['1_1', '1_2', '1_3', '1_4', '1_5', '1_6', '2_1', '2_2', '2_3', '2_4', '2_5', '2_6', '3_1', '3_2', '3_3', '3_4', '3_5', '3_6', '4_1', '4_2', '4_3', '4_4', '4_5', '4_6', '5_1', '5_2', '5_3', '5_4', '5_5', '5_6', '6_1', '6_2', '6_3', '6_4', '6_5', '6_6']
results ="d:\\Id.csv"
gf = pd.DataFrame({'Id' : [gen(l)]})
gf.to_csv(results, index=False)
```

The above code results in saving the result as Id header but the values are saved horizontally not vertically as column values. And it is saved as '1_1'... ,'2_1' so on . I want to save k in the above as result below without the quotations

```
result
      Id
      1_1
      1_2
      1_3
      1_4
      ...
      2_1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved the problem for me:

```
gf = pd.DataFrame({'Id' : gen(l)})  
gf.to_csv(results, index=False)
```